# Iterations always default to first project & can't select current project

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, azure-devops

I'm using the Team Foundation Service (TFS in the cloud) for source control. Within my account I have multiple projects. Via the website I can see that the first project has the default Release & Sprint hierarchy set. I have another project that I've created some releases & sprints. In the web admin I've also setup different areas for my project.

Within Visual Studio 2012, when I go to create a task (TEAM > NEW TASK), it always shows the AREA=[FirstProject] and the ITERATION options as only the [FirstProject]. I can't change the area to a different area or the iteration. It acts like Visual Studio is "stuck" within the [FirstProject] and won't let me get to any of my other projects when working with tasks & backlog items. However I can create tasks in the web client. Within Visual Studio I can also run queries and find tasks.

So, I'm trying to figure out how to make sure I can use Visual Studio 2012 to create & manage tasks and not have to go to the website each time. It acts stuck on one project. Ideas?

Note I'm not having issues with any of the other source control issues... it's just an issue with working with tasks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the "Team Explorer" in Visual Studio 2012 you can select the Team Project you need by clicking on:

- "Home | [FirstProject]", "Projects", and selecting a different one.

Also, in Visual Studio 2012.2 (Update 2) there is also a "Plug" looking icon at the top of Team Explorer, this allows access to many Servers, Collections and Team Projects from a panel in Team Explorer instead of a menu.

[image]

Comment: Ah... never realized that was a selectable control. Thanks!

Comment: @AndrewConnell - no problems, there's another way to do it in Update 2 (currently CTP). I've updated my answer.

Comment: Ah... thanks! The new minimalistic / Microsoft design / metro UI still fools me at times :)